# If the rock boundary exists, how did the planet Theia manage to collide with Earth?

Tags: earth, planets

Because it wasn't orbiting it, but in an errant orbit, but coinciding with that of the earth.

Much of its matter was absorbed by the Earth, and part was thrown into space, grouping together and forming the Moon.

Comment: How do meteors manage to collide with Earth? Lots of stuff got thrown around during the early stages of the solar system, including gas giants moving here and there (and maybe one or two getting tossed completely from the solar system).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.